# How can I split a string that has three spaces as its separators?

Tags: c#

I have written many lines to a text file and I have divided each line into parts by putting three spaces between parts. Here is an example of a line :

```
1   khashayar   home
```

Now I want to read and split each line by using

```
 arraytobeprinted = ss.Split('   ');
```

but I get this error:

> *There are too many characters in character literals*

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) for the same result.

```
string[] array2 = ss.Split(new string[]{"   "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: This answer is not correct it will actually produce the same result as `ss.Split(' ');` When the split string is converted with `ToCharArray` to a char array the char array is supposed to contain characters any of which, when encountered on its own in the input string, is a valid point for a split.

Comment: @mortb, you are absolutely right, I didn't know that, and just now I tried and it worked like you said. I have update the answer, and remove the part of ToCharArray. Thanks

Comment: For example ss.Split(['\t','\n'] would split on *either* tab *or* newline character and they would not necessarily have to be placed next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a character as a splitting delimiter. Try passing a string like this:

```
var parts = ss.Split(new[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: 
`ss.Split(new string [] {"   "}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Answer (score 0):

Use ss.Split(null) or ss.Split(new char[0]), this will solve your problem easiest way.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: That is no solution. It produces the same output as the statement `ss.Split(' ');` he had in his original program